# Connection refused : Testcontainer and Spring >3.1.x + Elastic 8

Tags: testcontainers, spring-3, elasticsearch-8

I have been running circle for quite some times and I suppose that I missed something in the documentation.
I wanted to upgrade our integration test using testcontainer and spring 3.1 update (esp the service connection). It works for the DB I am using but for elastic I had to do an extra step and move from 7.x to 8.1.x. Elastic 8.x. However I run into a nice connection refused loop.

I know that Elastic 8  brings default security enabled (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35926) however I disabled those. There is also a default password setup by the container (https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/main/modules/elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchContainer.java#L138).

Note that I do declare uri, username and password in application-test.yml, however they are not picked up because of this @ServiceConnection it seems. Or more so, they seem to be picked up but the container itself isn't bound to this address.
`spring.elasticsearch.username: user spring.elasticsearch.password: changeme spring.elasticsearch.uris: http://localhost:9200`

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Testcontainers
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Slf4j
public class FooControllerIT {
@Container
@ServiceConnection
static MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new      MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo").withTag("xxx"));
@Container
@ServiceConnection
static ElasticsearchContainer elasticsearchContainer = new ElasticsearchContainer(DockerImageName.parse("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch")
        .withTag("8.x"))
        .withEnv("xpack.security.enabled", "false")
        .withEnv("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled","false")
        .withEnv("xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled","false");

@Autowired
private SomeController someController;


@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    mongoDBContainer.start();
    elasticsearchContainer.start();//fails at startup or whenever trying to access one of its properties. <----
    Awaitility.await().atMost(Duration.ofMinutes(2)).until(() ->
            elasticsearchContainer.isRunning()); //<---- does not reach there so connection issue is not because the container is not yet opened 
   log.info("blabla"+elasticsearchContainer.isRunning()+","+elasticsearchContainer.isHostAccessible());
}
```

I suppose what is happening is that it tries to read the properties and picks up port 9200 while the container is initialized on another port.

Previously I could do something like that

```
public static class ElasticConfigInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        elasticsearchContainer.start();
        await().atMost(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(elasticsearchContainer::isRunning);
        String hostAddress = "http://" + elasticsearchContainer.getHttpHostAddress();
        TestPropertyValues.of(
                        "spring.elasticsearch.uris=" + hostAddress)
                .applyTo(applicationContext);
        log.info("finished Elastic config"+ elasticsearchContainer.getBoundPortNumbers()+","+elasticsearchContainer.getLogs());
    }
```

Is this still needed? I thought the new annotation @ServiceConnection was there to pickup the default values ?

Stacktrace :

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

What I am expecting is simply to get this @ServiceConnection working without having to override the default set up in my configuration. Is that possible? Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hello @Valentin, I think we should be able to make this work, because it works on my machine, I've just checked.
Perhaps it'd be easier for everyone if you could bring your issue to https://elasticstack.slack.com/ or https://discuss.elastic.co?
Disclaimer: I work for Elastic.
The idea is to avoid debug ping-pong here, but to bring a solution we'll be able to work out.
As for some hints already:
`xpack.security.enabled=false` alone should be enough (because Spring Boot doesn't support security yet)
I also don't get why you want to start the container in `@BeforeEach`...?